# Why is the body of this HTTP post null?

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSData object that represents a Facebook user provided by the IOS Facebook SDK.  This object is JSON formatted and I am attempting to post it to a server application.  Below is my Objective C code to execute the HTTP Post.  The problem with this code is that the request body is empty on the server.  Can someone spot what I've done wrong?

```
-(void)postUserDataToServer:(NSString *) user {

// Convert the JSON string to Data to be sent.

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ec2-whatever.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/user"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [user length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:user];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well ... user is  not NSData! you gotta transform the string into data

```
assert(user.length);
id bodyData = [user dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = bodyData;
```

Comment: btw: not answer but a recommendation: dont do synchronous networking

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why the length assertion is failing?

Comment: no, your code doesnt show where you init user or what that should be

Comment: Looks like I need to dig deeper into the facebook sdk.  Thanks again for the response.  It was the answer to the question as asked.